# iPhone App Dev - Edited mp3 files are not working in App

Tags: audio, mp3, edit, editing

In my application there are mp3 files located in the bundle (nothing from the web). Some of the mp3 files are original files and some I had edited using simple sound editing software (the ones where you insert a file, cut a slice of it and save it as a new and shorter mp3 file).

I'm using the AVAudioPlayer [initWithData] method.

All the original files (the ones that I hadn't edited and inserted to the bundle as is) are working perfectly and all the ones that were edited are not working at all.

I used 2 different editing software and the outcome is the same.

Anyone had ever encountered that or have any idea what may I done wrong?

Thanks,

Ohad

Answer (score 0):

Converting the mp3 to caf worked for me
as specified [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/_index.html).

see the following:

**How do I convert an audio file to the preferred format for iPhone OS?**

The preferred full-quality audio format for iPhone OS is 16-bit, little-endian, linear PCM packaged as a CAF file. To convert an audio file to this format, use the afconvert tool at the command line in Mac OS X, as shown in Listing 5.

Listing 5  Converting an audio file to the preferred format for iPhone OS

```
/usr/bin/afconvert -f caff -d LEI16 {INPUT} {OUTPUT}
```

To see all the options available for the afconvert tool, enter `afconvert -h` at the command line.